# Faster way to concatenate millions of dataframes without using pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have about 12 million dataframes stored in a one pickle file as list of dataframes. I want to concatenate these dataframes to have just one dataframe.

I have tried the following:

1. pd.concat this is quite slow.
2. suggestion from https://gist.github.com/TariqAHassan/fc77c00efef4897241f49e61ddbede9e , this takes about 24hrs.

Python code for 1:

'''

```
from src.utils import load_pickle 
data = load_pickle('the file path')
result = pd.concat(data)
```

'''

Python code for 2:

'''

```
def fast_flatten(input_list):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(input_list))
COLUMN_NAMES = data[0].columns
df_dict = dict.fromkeys(COLUMN_NAMES, [])
for col in tqdm(COLUMN_NAMES):
    extracted = (frame[col] for frame in data) # Use a generator to save memory
    df_dict[col] = fast_flatten(extracted)  # Flatten and save to df_dict
result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)[COLUMN_NAMES]
```

'''

The final result should be of size 20000042 by 47.

I will appreciate any efficient way to reduce the time from 24 hours.

Thanks

Comment: Does `concat` take more than 24h?

Comment: @cs95 I do not know how to wrap tqdm around pd.concat in order to tell the progress of the code...So I do not know if it takes lesser time.